# how to set an identity and get a certificate CN from an x509 encoded file in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, security, certificate

I am working on a Swift app which does a TLS connection to a server. I want to set an identity, which the server will validate. I'm given a x509 encoded pem file. The cert is not trusted locally on my system, but the server can validate it so it doesn't need to be trusted locally.

I don't need to import the cert, I just need to obtain an identity but I tried using **SecPKCS12Import** and **SecItemImport**.  Both return a success code, but no data.

I didn't need to import the cert - I just want to create an identity that I can use with my connection. But I try this:

`var importStatus = SecPKCS12Import(pkcs12Data as CFData, importOptions as CFDictionary, &importArray)`

The first time I call this, it's successful. I then try to extract the identity (and certificate) from the **importArray** returned, but in my case, even though I get an errSecSuccess return status, the importArray is empty.

*So first question: why would it be empty?*

( if the code is run again, I get an `errSecDuplicateItem` - I don't need to store it in the keychain but I guess I'm being forced to)

When I imported, I used a UUID as my identifier - I had set it in the options:

```
    let importOptions: [String: Any] = [
        kSecImportExportPassphrase as String: password,
        kSecImportItemLabel as String: identifier
    ]
```

So I try to retrieve the identity from the keychain:

```
    let identityQuery = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassIdentity,
        kSecReturnRef: true,
        kSecAttrLabel: identifier
    ] as NSDictionary
    
    var identityItem: CFTypeRef?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(identityQuery as CFDictionary, &identityItem)
```

where I pass the UUID as identifier, but I actually get back my apple identity, not the certificate. However, if I pass in the certificate's CN, (hard-coded for my testing) I get the right identity back.

*So my second question: am I doing something wrong? If i pass an ItemLabel on import, can I retrieve the certificate using that same label?*

So for me to get this working, I need to know the CN of my cert, or I need the ItemLabel to work so that I can just retrieve using a UUID.

To determine the CN of my cert, the only apple API I found is this:

```
SecCertificateCopyCommonName
```

which requires the cert to be in **.der** format, rather than **.pkcs12**. So I have a bit of a chicken and egg problem.

*So my last question - is there a way to extract the CN from the .pem file, or to convert the Data from .pem to .der?*

(As an alternative to

```
SecPKCS12Import
```

I try to use SecItemImport, passing in my data (as **pkcs12Data** parameter, same as  above)

```
    var inputFormat: SecExternalFormat = .formatPKCS12;
    var items : CFArray?
    let flags: SecItemImportExportFlags = SecItemImportExportFlags(rawValue: 0)
    
    var parameters = SecItemImportExportKeyParameters()
    parameters.accessRef = nil
    
    var itemType: SecExternalItemType = .itemTypeCertificate
    
    // Set import options
    let status = SecItemImport(pkcs12Data as CFData,
                              nil,
                               &inputFormat,
                               &itemType,
                               flags,
                               &parameters,
                               nil, // importKeychain
                               &items)
```

While this gives me proper `errSecSuccess` status, the items returned is empty, so I don't get any keychain items back.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.